# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' in TreeMix programme

Tags: c++, terminal, phylogeny

I'm trying to use the programme TreeMix to produce a phylogenetic tree, but this is the input and error:

```
treemix -i data.p.treemix.gz -o output

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My data looks to be in the proper format, and here is the header:

```
DEN NEA
2,0 0,2
0,2 2,0
...
```

The example files worked well so I don't think the programme itself is corrupted. The example file given looks like:

```
Han Sardinian Colombian Dai French Mozabite Karitiana Lahu BiakaPygmy She Italian San Yoruba 
2,66 2,54 0,10 1,19 4,52 6,48 0,24 2,14 31,13 0,20 3,23 6,6 21,21
```

The only differences between my data and the example I can think of is the fact that my data only contains 2s and 0s, there are only two populations, and the data overall contains a high level of missingness.

I can't change the programme itself as it is very complex, and as not an adept in C++ yet, I think I'd just muck it up.

I'd be grateful for any advice to help solve this issue!

Comment: you have to report bug to program devs, I'm afraid with providing a reproducible example of data causing this error

Comment: The example file seems to have only one data row, where your file has more than that.

Comment: @OlafDietsche That was my mistake! It has a lot of lines afterwards.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Thank you! When you submit an issue like this to the devs, do you just give them the files and the code you used?

Comment: something that allows them to reproduce the whole situation, in your case, yes, it would b your input. I assume that there should have been some protection against an edge case like that. In some cases that would be a backtrace because there might be "schrodinger bugs" which do not appear every time.